# undefined reference to 'setlinebuf'

Tags: c, printf, buffer, scanf

If I try to run the following simple code under TDM_GCC on Windows 10,

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main(){

  double input;

   setlinebuf(stdout);

    printf("Enter Your Input -");
    scanf("%If", &input);
    printf("Entered name is %f", input);

 return 0;
}
```

It compiles (via gcc) with an error which says that - undefined reference to 'setlinebuf'. I am using setlinebuf to have the buffer only buffer lines-wise.

Comment: Terminals are line buffered by default, so `setlinebuf(stdout);` won't really do anything unless you are redirecting output to a file.

Comment: You can replace `setlinebuf(stdout)` with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ)` (possibly replacing `BUFSIZ` with a different size). However, the Windows C runtime library treats `_IOLBF` as fully buffered, the same as `_IOFBF`, so for interactive usage, you may still need to call `ffflush(stdout)` after prompting for input, or alternatively, set `stdout` to to be unbuffered via `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

[setlinebuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlinebuf) is a non-standard function that requires a [feature macro](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros).

Feature macros switch on sets of functionality that are traditionally used in environments like Unix, but that haven't made it to the C standard.

Add the following line at the top of your code file (before including `stdio.h`) to switch on the declaration of `setlinebuf`:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

Note that the presence of optional features isn't mandatory, so it may not be available on your platform.

Comment: After including the line #define _BSD_SOURCE  before #include<stdio.h> again i got the same error message after compilation - undefined reference to 'setlinebuf'

Comment: It is possible (even probable) that the BSD features simply aren't available in Windows. After all, why would Microsoft add support for old BSD features in their version of libc?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the Eclipse's terminal emulator which i am using? I am using Eclipse NEON.

Comment: No, it depends on libc. Windows apparantly doesn't have any implementation of `setlinebuf` in its libc.